# Alertbox closing Automatically before Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I want show alertbox before intent in my activity.after click "ok" button only intent should work but in my case alertbox showing then immediately intent working.I mean alertbox closing automatically before intent.
this is my activity code

```
 alert.showAlertDialogpostive(ChangePass.this, "Successfully Submited",
                                    "Password Changed Successfully", true);

                        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                        userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                           Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                           // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                           dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                           startActivity(dashboard);
                           // Close Registration Screen
                           finish();
```

and this is my alert builder class

```
 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void showAlertDialogpostive(Context context, String title, String message,
            Boolean status) {
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);

        if(status != null)
            // Setting alert dialog icon
            alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.success);

        // Setting OK Button
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();

    }
```

Intent should work only after clicking ok button in alert box.help me !

Comment: move the intent code into your  onClick method of alert dialog

Comment: java is not the same as javascript when you put alert then the application will stop progressing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                    userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                       Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                       // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                       dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                       startActivity(dashboard);
                       // Close Registration Screen
                       finish();
```

Move above code inside alert's button click. So your code look like below,

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void showAlertDialogpostive(Context context, String title, String message,
        Boolean status) {
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);

    if(status != null)
        // Setting alert dialog icon
        alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.success);

    // Setting OK Button
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which) {
           UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                    userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                       Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                       // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                       dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                       startActivity(dashboard);
                       // Close Registration Screen
                       finish();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();

}
```